# Is $dy$ and $\Delta y$ just different in one is initial and other one is not?

Tags: calculus

Why sometimes we use $dy$ to find the relative error inetand of $\Delta y$?If we use$\Delta y$ the relative error will be more accurate isn't it?

I think of this question when I read this example.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwcdL.jpg)

Comment: Typically $\Delta y$ is a finite positive number while $dy$ means you consider the limit as $\Delta y$ approaches $0$. So the difference is in taking the limit.

Comment: The error is $\Delta y$ but using one or the other has nothing to do with accuracy. When we say $dy = f'(x)dx$ we are defining a linear approximation for the function $f$ at $x$ whose slope is $f'(x)$ with input variable $dx$ and output $dy$. When we use $dy$ to approximate $\Delta y$ we are saying that the change in the function, $\Delta y$, can be approximated by the linear function $dy=f'(x)dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EXAMPLE $4:$ The radius of a sphere was measured and found to be $21$ cm with a possible error in measurement of at most $0.05$ cm. What is the maximum error in using this value of the radius to compute the volume of the sphere?

Solution: Given, $\Delta r=0.05$ cm

Measured Volume, $V'=\frac{4}{3}\pi(21)^3$ cm$^3$

Real Volume, $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi(21+\Delta r)^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi(21.05)^3$ cm$^3$

$\therefore \Delta V=V-V'=\frac{4}{3}\pi[(21.05)^3-21^3]\approx277.75$ cm$^3$

So, $\Delta V \approx dV$.

$\Delta V$ is accurate but $dV$ is good approximation and more easier than to find $\Delta V$.